# WxPython Layout with Graph and Grid

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, wxpython

The layout is not working correctly. I want the screen split in equal parts. To the far left buttons in the middle a mathplotlib graph and to the right a grid. There are two problems mathplotlib graph does not appear centered and the grid is not to the far right.

I have tried changing the sizers and adding some flags to them.

```
import wx
import wx.grid as grid
from sympy import Symbol, sympify
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show, title, xlabel, ylabel
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

h = float()
xi = float()
yi = float()
fx = Symbol('fx')
xistr = np.array([])
yistr = np.array([])
istr = np.array([])
hstr = np.array([])
state = float()


class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        ###########
        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        left_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        center_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        right_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(left_sizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        main_sizer.Add(center_sizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        main_sizer.Add(right_sizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        ###########
        self.runbn = wx.Button(self, label="Run", size=(60, 30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Run, self.runbn)
        ############
        self.functionin = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(150, 30), style=wx.TE_CENTER)
        self.STRfxbn = wx.Button(self, -1, label="STR", size=(60, 30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.STRfc, self.STRfxbn)
        ############
        self.yiin = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(150, 30), style=wx.TE_CENTER)
        self.STRyibn = wx.Button(self, -1, label="STR", size=(60, 30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.STRyi, self.STRyibn)
        ############
        self.xiin = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(150, 30), style=wx.TE_CENTER)
        self.STRxibn = wx.Button(self, -1, label="STR", size=(60, 30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.STRxi, self.STRxibn)
        ############
        self.hiin = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(150, 30), style=wx.TE_CENTER)
        self.STRhibn = wx.Button(self, -1, label="STR", size=(60, 30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.STRhi, self.STRhibn)
        ###########
        self.resultbn = wx.Button(self, label="Results", size=(60, 30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.showresults, self.resultbn)
        ############

        left_sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self, -1, "f(x) for ODE"))
        left_sizer.Add(self.functionin, 0)
        left_sizer.Add(self.STRfxbn, 0)

        left_sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Initial y value"))
        left_sizer.Add(self.yiin, 0)
        left_sizer.Add(self.STRyibn, 0)

        left_sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Initial x value"))
        left_sizer.Add(self.xiin)
        left_sizer.Add(self.STRxibn)

        left_sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Initial step h"))
        left_sizer.Add(self.hiin)
        left_sizer.Add(self.STRhibn)

        left_sizer.Add(self.runbn, 0)
        left_sizer.Add(self.resultbn, 0)
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)

    def showresults(self, event):
        global istr
        global xistr
        global yistr
        global hstr
        resultgr = grid.Grid(self)
        resultgr.CreateGrid(30, 4)
        resultgr.SetColLabelValue(0, "Iteration")
        resultgr.SetColLabelValue(1, "X Value")
        resultgr.SetColLabelValue(2, "Y Value")
        resultgr.SetColLabelValue(3, "Step Size")
        r = 0
        i = 0
        for i in range(30):
            resultgr.SetCellValue(r, 0, str(round(istr[r], 4)))
            r = r + 1
            i = i + 1
        r = 0
        i = 0
        for i in range(30):
            resultgr.SetCellValue(r, 1, str(round(xistr[r], 4)))
            r = r + 1
            i = i + 1
        r = 0
        i = 0
        for i in range(30):
            resultgr.SetCellValue(r, 2, str(round(yistr[r], 4)))
            r = r + 1
            i = i + 1
        r = 0
        i = 0
        for i in range(30):
            resultgr.SetCellValue(r, 3, str(round(hstr[r], 4)))
            r = r + 1
            i = i + 1
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.axes.set_xlabel("x values")
        self.axes.set_ylabel("y values")
        self.axes.set_title("Prince-Dormand")
        self.axes.plot(xistr, yistr)
        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        left_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        center_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        right_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(left_sizer, 2, wx.EXPAND)
        main_sizer.Add(center_sizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        main_sizer.Add(right_sizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        center_sizer.Add(self.canvas, 0, wx.LEFT, 200)
        right_sizer.Add(resultgr, 0, wx.RIGHT, 0)
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)
        self.Fit()

... Following are button functions and main function which calculates values that go into graph and grid

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Prince-Dormand Method', size=(1300, 600))
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    resultgr = grid.Grid()
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

What should happen would be that each of the elements would be in its portion of the screen.

Comment: As it stands, your code is un-runnable. To improve your question, make all the values fixed, make the plot fixed. Get the code down to the bare basics. Also check your `for i in range` code, you don't have to increment i and r, use `i` that is what the `range` function does. The key to a good question, is to make it as easy as possible for someone to help. The basic layout should be simple enough but no one wants to plough through lines and lines of un-runnable code.

Comment: Would adding the complete code help?(Which is runnable)

Comment: The following provides advice on what is referred to as an `mcve` https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example The purpose is to make your question easy to answer `and` often in the process of creating it, you may well answer your own question, as having to think about the question in a different way or simplifying it, can give you an insight that you didn't have before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find below a working example having the widget distribution that you want.
The code below should be a good starting point for you to add all other widgets and methods as needed by your app.

```
import wx
import wx.grid as grid
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Prince-Dormand Method', size=(800, 600))

        ####---- Widgets
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        # Left Sizer Widgets here
        self.runbn = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Run", size=(60, 30))
        # Matplotlib plot here
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.panel, -1, self.figure)
        self.axes.set_xlabel("x values")
        self.axes.set_ylabel("y values")
        self.axes.set_title("Prince-Dormand")
        # Grid here
        self.resultgr = grid.Grid(self)
        self.resultgr.CreateGrid(30, 4)
        self.resultgr.SetColLabelValue(0, "Iteration")
        self.resultgr.SetColLabelValue(1, "X Value")
        self.resultgr.SetColLabelValue(2, "Y Value")
        self.resultgr.SetColLabelValue(3, "Step Size")
        ####---- Sizers
        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        left_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        center_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        right_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        left_sizer.Add(self.runbn, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        center_sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        right_sizer.Add(self.resultgr, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        main_sizer.Add(left_sizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        main_sizer.Add(center_sizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        main_sizer.Add(right_sizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.panel.SetSizer(main_sizer)
        main_sizer.Fit(self.panel)
    #---
#---

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Many Thanks. There are however two questions I have. Why arent all the boxes created by the sizers the same size?How can it be prevented that part of the grid is outside the window?

Comment: In principle, since you are using a wx.BoxSizer for main_sizer they should be exactly the same size. The problem with the grid is that the figure is wider than the grid. Since the main_sizer gives the same width to both center_sizer and right_sizer the bottom white panel in the grid gets wider and beyond the cells. Change the size of the figure to 4,4 to see the difference. Do you really need all the sections to be the same width? You might be better with a wx.FlexGridSizer for the main_sizer.